# How to matrix transpose using morton order?

Tags: c, matrix, transpose, cache-oblivious, z-order-curve

I want to transpose matrix by using morton order for imporve matrix transpose.

I found some article about morton order, but i can't understand how to use that.

especially, [image]

and

[image]

I want to invert this matrix A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16] (linear address)

to

B = [1 2 5 6; 3 4 7 8; 9 10 13 14; 11 12 15 16;].

and then transpose.

But I can't solve it.....

Someone who know principle about this transformation?

Really thanks in advance.